# How to use breakpoints in eclipse with JRuby on Rails

Tags: eclipse, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, jruby, jrubyonrails

I have been searching on how to use breakpoints in Eclipse when running a JRuby on Rails application.

I installed ruby-debug and ruby-debug-ide, but now I don't know how to proceed.

If I put 'debugger' somewhere in my code and start up my WEBrick server with --debugger, then I'm able to use the Ruby debugger with commands like 'step'. But is there a way to use breakpoints and inspect variables?

Comment: hi, I must admit that for Ruby I use Netbeans but I think it should be the same, break point and watchs should work the same as in any other language. Are you starting webrick from eclipse?